# What is the difference between using 'config.log_level' and 'Rails.logger.level'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I've seen examples of both statements, and both control the level of logging whether using descriptive values (:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, :unknown) or numeral (1-5).

Answer (score 1):

`config.log_level` is only used in environment initializer files.

`Rails.logger.level` can be used almost anywhere.

See this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels).

I have never set log-level anywhere else than in my env.-initializer files. I guess maybe one possible usecase for using `Rails.logger.level` could be when for ex. you have a development environment so it has a log-level of `:debug` but you don't want to bloat you log files with a lot of db-querys and unneccessary debug-info- then you can filter out only info-level log:

```
Rails.logger.level = 1
# Some code that gives out too much debug information
Rails.logger.level = 0
# Code that's ok for debug information
```

And respectively in prod-env. if you, for some reason, want to print out debug info in a certain place of the code while environment log level is set to `:info`.

Comment: What do you mean "almost anywhere"? I'm not really clear on the difference, even after reading the documentation.